# custom view not getting drawn in custom viewgroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, viewgroup, android-viewgroup

I have a custom view class that draws a rectangle and I have a custom view group where I am trying to add these custom views but somehow the views are not getting drawn properly(at times only one of the view gets drawn).
Not able to locate the problem!

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private CustomTaskView customTaskView;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    customTaskView = new CustomTaskView(MainActivity.this);


    frameLayout = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
    frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


    Paint blackPaint = new Paint();
    blackPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    blackPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    CustomView customView1 = new CustomView(MainActivity.this, 100, 50, 100, 300, blackPaint);

    customView1.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    frameLayout.addView(customView1);


    Paint redPaint = new Paint();
    redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    redPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    CustomView customView2 = new CustomView(MainActivity.this, 200, 50, 300, 400, redPaint);
    customView2.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    frameLayout.addView(customView2);



    setContentView(frameLayout);
  }

}
```

CustomView.java

```
public class CustomView extends View {

private Paint paint;

private float l, t, r, b;

public CustomView(Context context, float l, float t, float r, float b, Paint paint) {
    super(context);
    this.b = b;
    this.l = l;
    this.r = r;
    this.t = t;
    this.paint = paint;
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(l, t, r, b, paint);
}
}
```

CustomTaskView.java(the custom viewgroup file)

```
public class CustomTaskView extends ViewGroup implements LongPressGestureListener.HandleClicks {

int width, height;
private GestureDetectorCompat mGestureDetector;
private LongPressGestureListener longPressGestureListener;
private Map<Integer, List<Point>> map;


public CustomTaskView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    longPressGestureListener = new LongPressGestureListener(context, CustomTaskView.this);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, longPressGestureListener);
    map = new HashMap<>();
}

public CustomTaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomTaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

}


@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    width = getMeasuredWidth();
    height = getMeasuredHeight();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    // Handle any other event here, if not long press.
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
public void handleLongClick(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.e("ganesh", "handling long clicks!");
}

@Override
public void handleSingleClick(MotionEvent event) {

    float xCoordinate = event.getX();
    float yCoordinate = event.getY();

    Point tempPoint = new Point(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);

    int count = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Point>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (isPointInside(entry.getValue(), tempPoint))
            count++;
    }

    Log.e("ganesh", "handling single clicks!" + xCoordinate + " " + yCoordinate + " count: " + count);


}


public boolean isPointInside(List<Point> pointList, Point targetPoint) {
    return targetPoint.getxCoordinate() >= pointList.get(0).getxCoordinate() && targetPoint.getxCoordinate() <= pointList.get(1).getxCoordinate() && targetPoint.getyCoordinate() >= pointList.get(0).getyCoordinate() && targetPoint.getyCoordinate() <= pointList.get(2).getyCoordinate();
}
```

}

Comment: inside `CustomView#onDraw` log the values of `l`, `t`, `r` and `b`, what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: I am currently working on providing the correct implementation of onLayout and onMeasure. as far as I have understood I'll have to get the measurements of child views in onMeasure and for positioning, onLayout will be used

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make any change to a custom view, you need to rebuild your project for the XML preview parser to draw. Try `Build`->`Rebuild Project` once.

Comment: Not working! Doesn't the project get rebuilt when we run the app? why do we need to rebuild it again?

Comment: your `onLayout` method is not calling `super` check once.

Comment: super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
after adding this line I'm getting this error: Abstract method can't be accessed directly

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the correct implementation of **onLayout** and **onMeasure** method in your custom view if you extend ViewGroup class directly. You can find out more about these two methods here [Google Developers Guide Custom ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup)

Well here is the edit to your current CustomTaskView.java to make your code work.

```
 @Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        CustomView customView = (CustomView) this.getChildAt(i);
        customView.layout(l, t, r, b);
    }
}
```

In Custom View **onLayout** method is responsible for Position all children within the layout. You need to call **layout** method on all the children and provide calculated left, top, right, bottom attribute to them.